# Hello world contract method call returns Unhandled rejection Error

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "solc": "^0.4.16",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.20"
  }
}
```

This is my smart contract code:

```
contract HelloWorld {
    function displayMessage() constant returns (string) {
        return "Hello from a smart contract";
    }
}
```

I've compiled this contract on the node repl with testprc running, and I'm trying to call the `displayMessage` method like so:

```
myContract.methods.displayMessage().call()
```

or

```
myContract.methods.displayMessage.call()
```

but I'm just getting this error:

```
> Unhandled rejection Error: ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string:
at SolidityTypeString.formatOutputString [as _outputFormatter] (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/formatters.js:245:15)
at /Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/type.js:246:25
at SolidityTypeString.SolidityType.decode (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/type.js:247:11)
at /Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:327:49
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:326:13)
at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:490:22)
at Method._parent._ethereumCall.call.method.outputFormatter (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:820:42)
at Method.formatOutput (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:179:54)
at sendTxCallback (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:446:33)
at /Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:144:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:64:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/alberthu/Documents/solidity-intro/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

I've tried reading through the web3 api docs but I'm new to this and haven't found anything useful. Anyone know how I can get "Hello from a smart contract" to show on the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. And insert correct contract address.
My contract (example from [documentation web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html)) I use web3.1.0.0-beta.23.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MyContract {
function myFunction() returns(uint256 myNumber, string myString) {
    return (23456, "Hello!%");
   }
}
```

code

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);  
contract.methods.myFunction().call()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(e => console.log(e.message))
```

contract creating and send from test net good. But if I tried call methods - have the same error:

```
ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string:
```

Comment: I have the same error. If test contract methods in testrpc - all methods work fine, but if I run the same code on geth server - catch error. Use command for get `geth --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --ws --wsaddr "localhost" --wsport "8545" --wsorigins "*" --identity "MyTestNode" --datadir "./data" --rinkeby --fast`

Comment: I am also facing same error. @AndreyPatseiko did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning how to code smart contracts and came across this error earlier today. I found what was causing it was that I had the wrong address tied to my smart contract.

Contract objects in web3 have an address property which represents the address used for that contract instance. In my case this address was incorrect and was causing me to have the same error. The contract address should have been returned to you after your deployment.

The correct contract address should have been returned to you in a callback function after you deployed it.

You can set and check your contract address as follows:

```
myContract.options.address // returns the current address you have set for this contract instance
myContract.options.address = "the correct contract address"
```

I would have left this as a comment but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation. Let me know if you need some more help or want to get together to learn.

Here is the web3js documentation on contract address property: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#options-address